# Installing interactive brokers IB gateway on raspy 3B+

Tags: ubuntu, java, bugs

I found some posts that walk you through the installation but they are very old and don’t work anymore. I tried to install the oracle java for Arm Linux and then modify the IB installation script to point to the newly installed version of java but when running the script is says that it is corrupted.

I was following this guide: [Trading on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 16.04](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2018/01/04/trading-with-raspberry-pi/).

Java version installed 1.8.0_65

After installing java the guide says to uncomment this line:

```
#INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=
```

and point it to the installed java.

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE= /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/bin/java
```

After doing this the installer gives me this message

> gzip: sfx_archive.tar.gz: not in gzip format I am sorry, but the installer file seems to be corrupted. If you downloaded that file please try it again. If you transfer that file with ftp please make sure that you are using binary mode.

The installer I am using is: `ibgateway-stable-standalone-linux-x86.sh`

Please help

Comment: What is interactive brokers IB gateway?

Comment: @Ingo an application that has to be constantly running in order to access the interactive brokers api

Comment: But it MUST not run on a Raspberry Pi, right? Does it need Java? What script exactly do you use?

Comment: If there is no way to run it on the pi I would have to buy a more expensive linux machine to do the job I originally bought the pi for... would be nice if I could get it to run on the pi

Comment: Thank you, I deleted my comments and edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you edit the shell script in binary mode! It sounds like you may have edited it as plain text. (eg. use vi -b)